# How to play all music continually from playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to play music from playlist. Need javascript function to play dynamically all songs continually.

**Simple Player**

```
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="">
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="music/demo.mp3">
    Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>
```

**Playlist**

```
<ul id="playlist">
  <?php if($lists) { foreach ($lists as $key=> $list) { ?>
    <li class="active">
      <a src="music/<?php  echo $list;  ?>.mp3">
         <?php  echo $list;  ?> </a>
    </li>   
  <?php }}?>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;

    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('src');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

I have 3 songs in playlist but the problem is it only plays the first 2 songs and the player skip last song and repeat the playlist again without play the last song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are increasing the `current` index before checking if it is the last one that is actually being played. Do this:

```
audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){

    if(current == len){
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find('a')[0];
    }else{
        link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        current++; // <-- Increment after the check
    }
    run($(link),audio[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @zhertal can you suggest how to stop music after last song played from playlist?

Comment: You could move the last line (`run($(link),audio[0]);`) inside the else, just after `current++` so that it doesn't get called when the `current` variable is reset.

Comment: Working on firefox,chrome and ie but not working on opera and safari. When i click on a song from playlist, nothing plays on audio `<source>` tag but when i remove playlist and add a single song in audio `<source>` tag it works fine. @Zhertal